# Altair Multiline Axis Labels Break Stacked Bar Charts

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to use multi-line labels for a stacked bar chart, but running into the problem replicated with sample code below. Trying to use the regular textwrap lists for axis labels results in broken stacked bar charts as seen in the image. Can anyone tell me why or if there is a work-around?

Altair version 5.0.0

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import textwrap

source = data.barley()
source['multiline_label'] = source['variety'].apply(textwrap.wrap, args=[5])

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield)').stack("normalize"),
    y='multiline_label',
    color='site'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around and a lot of rooting through the documentation, I managed to find a workaround. After splitting the labels with textwrap.wrap, you can re-join them on some separator (I used '_'). Then, you can use labelExpr within an axis configuration to re-split the labels on that separator. Revised code and result below.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import textwrap

source = data.barley()
source['multiline_label'] = source['variety'].apply(textwrap.wrap, args=[5])
source['multiline_label'] = source['multiline_label'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x))

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield)').stack("normalize"),
    y='multiline_label:N',
    color='site'
).configure_axisY(
    labelExpr = 'split(datum.label, "_")'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two other possible solutions; first, just cutting the label length:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import textwrap

source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield)').stack("normalize"),
    y=alt.Y('variety').axis(labelLimit=40),
    color='site'
)
```

Second, using [the built in Vega expressions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#string-functions) to slice the string instead of pandas

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import textwrap

source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source, height=alt.Step(30)).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield)').stack("normalize"),
    y=alt.Y('variety').axis(labelExpr='[slice(datum.label, 0, 4), slice(datum.label, 4)]', labelOffset=-5),
    color='site'
)
```

Comment: Oh, yeah I should clarify that the sticking point for me was that I really needed the functionality from the textwrap library. The labels in the sample data are short, but in my actual project, the labels were full survey questions so they needed to be fully displayed and properly wrapped as a text block rather than sliced at arbitrary locations of the string.